# How to AspectFit a UIBezierPath in iOS using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I'm trying to AspectFit a UIBezierPath based custom button.

Here is my code in a custom class which subclass from UIButton Class

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
   if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {
    self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
   }
   return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

 UIColor* fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.451 green: 0.855 blue: 1 alpha: 1];

UIBezierPath* clipPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0.01, 81.6, 40.9)];
[clipPath addClip];

UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(81.21, 13.63)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(48.11, 40.91) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(84.3, 37.04) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(68.27, 40.91)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(4.72, 45.04) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(33.83, 40.91) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(3.32, 40.91)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(20.19, 7.94) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(-1.03, 14.37) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(-1.26, 0.28)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(81.21, 13.63) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(40.97, 1.57) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(78.62, -6.04)];
[bezierPath closePath];
[fillColor setFill];
[bezierPath fill];
}
```

In the xib, I assigned the custom class to the UIButton object. I tried using AspectFit handlers in IB and as well as tried in the initWithCoder, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably to apply an aspectFit transform to the BezierPath before you draw it, or to apply the same transform to the graphics context. Something like the following:

```
- (CGAffineTransform) aspectFitFrom:(CGRect)originalRect to:(CGRect)targetRect
{
    CGFloat xScale = targetRect.size.width / originalRect.size.width;
    CGFloat yScale = targetRect.size.height / originalRect.size.height;
    CGFloat scale = MIN(xScale, yScale);

    CGFloat xShift = CGRectGetMidX(targetRect) - CGRectGetMidX(originalRect) * scale;
    CGFloat yShift = CGRectGetMidY(targetRect) - CGRectGetMidY(originalRect) * scale;
    return CGAffineTransformMake(scale, 0, 0, scale, xShift, yShift);
}
```

Apply that to the bounding box of the Bezier path, and the bounds of the target. Then apply the transform to the bezierPath before filling it, as follows:

```
CGRect pathBBox = bezierPath.bounds; // the bounding box of your bezierPath
CGAffineTransform transform = [self aspectFitFrom:pathBBox to:rect];
[bezierPath applyTransform:transform];
```

You need to think yourself what you want to do with the line thickness of the shape when it gets scaled.

Comment: As of speaking about my code, how would I apply this transformation? The objects are not programmatically drawn in view.

Comment: Your objects ARE programmatically drawn in the view. That is what the drawRect: does.

Answer (score 0):

I carefully estimated the width and height of the drawing and it gave me 82 x 42 ponts. I then applied a scale factor in the code so the drawing could fit the button if the button size is scaled in the xib.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextScaleCTM(context, rect.size.width / 82, rect.size.height/ 42);
```

The complete code looks like this now.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextScaleCTM(context, rect.size.width / 82, rect.size.height/ 42);

  {

  UIColor* fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.451 green: 0.855 blue: 1 alpha: 1];


  UIBezierPath* clipPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(0, 0.01, 81.6, 40.9)];
  [clipPath addClip];

  UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];


  [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(81.21, 13.63)];
  [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(48.11, 40.91) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(84.3, 37.04) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(68.27, 40.91)];
  [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(0.72, 25.04) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(33.83, 40.91) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(3.32, 40.91)];
  [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(20.19, 0.94) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(-1.03, 14.37) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(-1.26, 0.28)];
  [bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(81.21, 13.63) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(40.97, 1.57) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(78.62, -6.04)];
  [bezierPath closePath];
  [fillColor setFill];
  [bezierPath fill];

  }

}
```